# ElementTree from python doesn't find a child tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, urllib2, elementtree

I'm trying to access an element from a `XML` file from `Python` with `ElementTree`, and it doesn't find it.

XML code:

```
<item>
        <id>12345678</id>
        <subs>
            <sub category="A">
                <name>Name 1 text</name>
                <file>File 1 text</file>
            </sub>
            <sub category="B">
                <name>Name 2 text</name>
                <file>File 2 text</file>
            </sub>
        </subs>
        <number>Number text</number>
        <title>Title text</title>
</item>
```

I want to read the `file` tag text:

Python code:

```
import urllib2
import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.ElementTree(file=urllib2.urlopen('http://..../filename.jsp?id=12345678')).getroot()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for subtags in root.findall('sub'):
        filetext = subtags.find('file').text
        print(filetext)
```

The output would have to be this:

```
> File 1 text
> File 2 text
```

But, the output I get is nothing (blank), then, after 10 seconds the program stops running, without getting any error.

I've tried it with the other tags from the `XML` and **it works**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`findall` looks for direct children only, if you give it tag name.

You can search in all descendants with `XPath` query like:

```py
root.findall('.//sub')
```

Comment: I've tried, and I get that error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Myfile.py", line 51, in <module>
    filetext = subtags.find('file').text  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

I think the problem's that method `findall` returns a `None` object instead of an `Element` object

Comment: That's a different issue, and you should be fine parsing the XML file you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, For reference only.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,utils,req
html = '''<item>
        <id>12345678</id>
        <subs>
            <sub category="A">
                <name>Name 1 text</name>
                <file>File 1 text</file>
            </sub>
            <sub category="B">
                <name>Name 2 text</name>
                <file>File 2 text</file>
            </sub>
        </subs>
        <number>Number text</number>
        <title>Title text</title>
</item>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
files = doc.selects('sub').file.text
print(files)
```

Result:

```
['File 1 text', 'File 2 text']
```